# How to stub a HTTParty request inside a method for testing?

Tags: ruby, minitest, httparty, webmock

I have created a function that makes a HTTParty get request. It raises a custom error message that i need to test. I tried to stub the request using Webmock in the test but it is raising a `<Net::OpenTimeout>`. How can i stub the get request if the url is dynamically constructed?

```
def function(a , b)
# some logic , dynamic url constructed
response = HTTParty.get(url, headers: {"Content-Type" => 
 "application/json"})
if response.code != 200
  raise CustomError.new <<~EOF
    Error while fetching job details.
    Response code: #{response.code}
    Response body: #{response.body}
  EOF
end
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

for the test

```
def test_function
WebMock.stub_request(:get, url).with(:headers => {'Content- 
  Type'=>'application/json'}).to_return(:status => 500)
# HTTParty.stub(get: fake_response)
err = assert_raises CustumError do
   c.function(a , b)
end
```

Comment: What is `# some logic , dynamic url constructed`? That information may be fundamental to the solution.

Comment: The url has a base form with a and b appended eg. http://example.com/v1/#{a}

Comment: Could you just show the code, instead of only trying to summarise what the code does? I could easy misinterpret that description and, even if I do interpret it correctly, maybe your code isn't actually doing what you think it is.

Comment: As already answered below, one *possible* solution could be to match the request URL with a regex. But without really knowing what pattern you're generating, I cannot give a concrete answer nor verify whether it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebMock allows you to use "wildcard matching" so you can [stub requests matching a regular expression](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-uris-using-regular-expressions):

```
WebMock.stub_request(:get, /example/).to_return(status: 500)
```

Comment: I tried passing the regular expression and it still didn't work.. Is the assertion correct?

Comment: Try removing the block from your `assert_raises`.  Also, if you supply headers to webmock, it's possible there are other headers present that are preventing the match